# word VBA changing form field to number

Tags: vba, ms-word, formfield

Im am using Word VBA to create a form field and then insert a value into that field.

Problem is I need to change the data type of the field I have created.

Code:

```
  ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("Loan_Amount").Select
  ActiveDocument.FormFields.Add FFHere, wdFieldFormTextInput
  ActiveDocument.FormFields("Text1").Result = Value
```

Had a hunt around but can't find anything on the topic. It would also be nice to change the name of the bookmark of the field (calls itself "Text1" by default).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It would also be nice to change the name of the bookmark of the field (calls itself "Text1" by default).

Like this?

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim ff As FormField

    ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("Loan_Amount").Select

    Set ff = ActiveDocument.FormFields.Add(FFHere, wdFieldFormTextInput)
    ff.Name = "BlahBlah"
End Sub
```

And here is an example which inserts a Text field but changes it to Date Field

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim ff As FormField
    Set ff = ActiveDocument.FormFields.Add(FFHere, wdFieldFormTextInput)
    ff.Select
    With Selection.FormFields(1)
        '~~> Change Name Here
        .Name = "BlahBlah"
        '~~> Change Type here
        With .TextInput
            .EditType Type:=wdCurrentDateText, Default:="", Format:=""
            .Width = 0
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

Other type that you can change it to are

1. `wdCurrentDateText`
2. `wdCalculationText`
3. `wdCurrentTimeText`
4. `wdDateText`
5. `wdNumberText` (This is what your question requested for)

**NOTE**: I am assuming that `FFHere` is a valid range

Comment: Awesome, works for the bookmake name.

Any idea how to change the Type? Using the above method it gives me "Can't assign to read-only property"

Comment: I have updated the post which answers your 2nd question as well :) You might want to refresh the page?

Comment: Ahh wow, much appreacited!

Will come back and Vote this up when I get enough rep :)